# Crystal Reports OLE DB Missing database

Tags: c#, ado, ole, crystal-reports-2008

Small but annoying issue with crystal reports. I have a report connecting to a database on a server using OLE DB (ADO).

I've hard coded the connection string (all info inc. user & pass) so it should just load straight into the report and it does do this, on some machines :(.

On other machines when you load the report it brings up the login box with the server, user name and password all filled in. The database however is left blank and is greyed out so no changes can be made.

Does anyone have ideas why this is and any fixes. Sorry for lack of information but I really don't know the cause. I've checked setup differences between machines and can't find any that I felt would account for the issue. Both have the VS crystal reports redist plugins, both have System.Data.dll

Thanks in advance, any thoughts are welcome (will try anything at this point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.

I switched from using SQL Native Client connection to Microsoft OLE DB for SQL Server